# bookdown: punctuation between table numbering and table caption in docx output with knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

In the old bookdown (I forgot the version), there is a punctuation, such as `:`, between table number and the content of table caption. For example, it may be like `Table 1`**:**`XXXX`. However, it seems the punctuation losses in the newest bookdown. The caption now is `Table 1 XXXX`. But I like the punctuation more than without it. The following is an example.

````
---
output: bookdown::word_document2
---

```{r results = 'asis', echo = FALSE, eval = T}
data <- data.frame(ColA = c(1, 2, 3), colB = c('abc', 'def', 'ghi'))
kable(data, format = 'pandoc', booktabs = TRUE, longtable = TRUE, caption = 'test table')
```
````

Save the codes as `test1.Rmd`. After that attach the package bookdown and run

```
rmarkdown::render('test1.Rmd', output_format = 'word_document2', quiet = T)
```

the table caption is `Table 1`**:**`test table` with the **old** *knitr*, but now is `Table 1 test table`.

So my question goes as follows.

1. Is there a way to add the punctuation between table number and content of table caption with the newest bookdown?
2. If there is a way, could I change the punctuations, such from : to ., or from . to $. with the newest bookdown?

Comment: Currently this is hardcoded, and you cannot change it, but you can file an issue on Github, and I may take a look in the future. Thanks!